# in jira server my burndown does not reflect my done work

Tags: jira, burndowncharts

I'm using a jira server with a custom workflow and some custom boards so, it could definitely be that I spoiled it but ..  so far it was working perfect.

We tried starting a sprint, added some issues to the sprint (do not estimate them) and the burndown plot was looking dandy. At some point we rejected a task and the burndown was going down, good.
We added one surprise task and the burndown was going up, good.

But when we move tasks to DONE the burndown does NOT go down ... why ?

Here is our burndown: 
[image]
(please notice end time : June 2)
(please notice the only movement down is due to RX118 being rejected. Not RX119 being done (we will investigate more on RX119)

Here the list of activity where you can see it just says we rejected one and added one. You can see how RX-119 is in the list:
[image: list of issues]

But here you can see how RX-119 is DONE...
[image]

Here you can see my columns in the sprint board. Done column matches DONE status. And anyhow one could se in the issue that it was DONE.

[image: columns in the board]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

It appears the Done status was not in right-most column of the sprint board.

In Jira the issue journey should start from the Backlog or the left-most column of the board and build it's way to the right-most column. Reaching the right-most represents items in a 'successful' state.

Once you map the Done status to the right column then Burndown chart will be updated.

---

**Original Answer**

I'll explain how the burndown chart is displayed:

**Estimation statistic**: The vertical axis represents the estimation statistic that you've selected.

**Remaining values**: The red line represents the total amount of work left in the sprint, according to your team's estimates.

**Guideline**: The grey line shows an approximation of where your team should be, assuming linear progress. If the red line is below this line, congratulations - your team's on track to completing all their work by the end of the sprint. This isn't foolproof though; it's just another piece of information to use while monitoring team progress.

From your indication that the red line in the burndown chart only went down when one issue was canceled, which means that issue has an estimation.

Understanding the estimation statistic

On the left side of the chart you'll find the estimation for the burndown:

[image]

1- shows that the estimation used for this burndown is story points.

Check what your estimation is, and verify that all the done issue has value using that estimation strategy

Comment: hi, I updated the picture of the burndown so you can see we are using issue count. That's why it went one step down when rejecting one issue and one step up when adding one. If I set it to story points (the only other option) I see a flat line ... which makes sense since every issue is estimated as 0 points. So .. this doesnt seam to be the problem ..

Comment: Okay then could you verify the resolution date of issue is set during the sprint

Comment: Also one more issue might be the rightmost column on the Board doesnt contain Done

Comment: updated images so you can check the times of the sprint and the resolution time of the issue

Comment: added the columns of the board. Anyhow don't thing that's the problem since in the issue details one can see it is actually "DONE"

Comment: The rightmost column on the Board should contain Done, if you want it to be considered done on the sprint burndown

Comment: could your post it as an asnwer? This was my actual problem. Thanks !

Comment: Anytime I'm glad that we found the root cause of the issue. I have updated the answer to reflect it